# What is "wall riding"?

Tags: terminology

I have read the term "wall riding" somewhere .. what does it mean? It was related to car games.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Wall riding is when you take advantage of non-realistic physics in driving games and rub up against walls when cornering and passing.

As an extreme example, in some of the older Gran Turismo games you could do the endurance races on the high speed (nearly circular) track by using a very fast car and pinning it to the outside wall. You could literally use rubber bands on the controller to hold the car to the wall and let the game play itself.

More modern racing games have become more realistic, and this technique no longer works as well (or at all).

Comment: The basic idea is that you enter the corner at such a high speed so that normally you would lose control and wreck, but since your car is against the outside wall it basically slingshots you around the corner at high speed while maintaining control.

Comment: wall riding like it is in the games is exaggerated. But it works see (i don't think that it would with a car :P ): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_vOC9W1xxM

Comment: This talk about how unrealistic it is to wall ride is nonsense. I saw it on NASCAR this weekend: https://twitter.com/NASCARonNBC/status/1586834658028703744

Answer (score 3):

If what you heard was in relation to TrackMania, the term means something completely different. In TrackMania, cars can literally ride on their sides on walls if they have sufficient speed/momentum. Special track parts (called blocks in TrackMania) can allow cars to ride vertical walls that can even loop overhead.

Comment: Trackmania's great, but RollCage took wallriding to the logical extreme.

Answer (score 1):

This is also a thing in Tony Hawk Pro Skater-style games, if you are mostly parallel to a wall and ollie up towards it you can ride your skateboard/bike/whatever sideways on the wall for a short period of time. Can use it to string together combos like doing a manual.